# ember-data: Updating a record with a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: ember.js, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, ember-data

I have a File and a Tag model, which are in a many-to-many relationship:

```
App.File = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag')

App.Tag = DS.Model.extend
  name: DS.attr('string')
  files: DS.hasMany('file')
```

I'm reading the data as JSON generated via Rails backend, and so far everything works fine.  I'm trying to write a `tagFile` function in my Ember route that tags a file with a specific tag.  This works fine on the ember side but of course it doesn't persist, and I can't figure out how to send the proper HTTP request to the Rails backend.  So I have

```
App.FilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  ...
  actions:
    tagFile: (file, tag) ->
      file.get('tags').pushObject(tag)
      tag.get('files').pushObject(file)
      # file.save() ? or something similar?
```

I've tried `file.save()`, which sends a PUT request, but the sent `params` hash in Rails does not include the `Tag` record at all.  I set a breakpoint in the `updateRecord()` method inside ember-data, and examined the `data` variable before it gets sent via AJAX, and this variable does not include the `Tag` record either.

What is the correct way to send an HTTP request (PUT or otherwise) where I can pass along my child record into the `params` hash?  Is there a way to pass arbitrary data using ember-data methods?  I could write my own AJAX call but then it seems like I'm not taking advantage of ember-data.  Any insights?

Using: Ruby 2/Rails 4 backend, Ember 1.3.0-beta.1+canary.48513b24, Ember-data 1.0.0-beta.4+canary.c15b8f80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 file.get('tags').pushObject(tag);
 tag.save();
 file.save();
```

Dual hasMany will connect them together http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/94/edit

If you want to create a custom serializer for one of the types to include the other.  Here's a slightly modified one from ED

```
App.FileSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   serialize: function(record, options) {
    var json = {};

    if (options && options.includeId) {
      var id = get(record, 'id');

      if (id) {
        json[get(this, 'primaryKey')] = get(record, 'id');
      }
    }

    record.eachAttribute(function(key, attribute) {
      this.serializeAttribute(record, json, key, attribute);
    }, this);

     var tags = [];
    record.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship) {
      if (relationship.kind === 'belongsTo') {
        this.serializeBelongsTo(record, json, relationship);
      } else if (relationship.kind === 'hasMany') {
        record.get(relationship.key).forEach(function(tag){
          tags.push(tag.toJSON());
        });
        //this.serializeHasMany(record, json, relationship);
      }
    }, this);

    json.tags = tags;

    return json;
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/95/edit

Or a more specific serializer

```
App.FileSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   serialize: function(record, options) {
    var json = {}, 
        tags=[];

    json.id = record.get('id'); 
    json.name = record.get('name');

    record.get('tags').forEach(function(tag){
      var tagJson = {};
      tagJson.id = tag.get('id');
      tagJson.name = tag.get('name');
      tags.push(tagJson);
    });

    json.tags = tags;

    return json;
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/96/edit

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!  For your first solution, involving 2 saves, my code seems to send two PUT requests, one to `file#update` and one to `tag#update`.  Did I make a mistake somewhere?  I want it to send one PUT request to `file#update` and have the `tag` record available.  Also, would overriding the serializer affect the rest of my code, which works as is with `ActiveRecordSerializer` using side-loaded JSON?

Comment: gotcha, I'd go with the third example, and remove the save on the tag.  serialize is just used for put/post.  You'll see how I did `FileSerializer` it will only be used for file records.  Here's one with the `ActiveModelSerializer` http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/97/edit